# How to connect Hosting cPanel with Visual Studio Code using SFTP

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, ftp, cpanel, sftp

I know **how to connect cPanel with visual studio code editor using ftp-simple** extension but I want to connect with it **SFTP** method **which is more secure than FTP**.

I have also connected it using SFTP  extension but the problem is, when I am trying to edit any file it says: **Read only editor.**

It is unable to edit files but **using ftp-simiple extension I can edit.**

So, what can we problem here?

Is there any other **sftp extension for connecting cpanel to vscode?**